# django for permisosin ,add ,delete ,change

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-permissions

I have Post model and I want to allow a user to add, change and delete.

global | post | User can add a post
global | post | User can delete the post

global | post | User can change post

can someone help me ??

I try this in my views and its gives the error.
this error
"User matching query does not exist."

```
User.objects.get_or_create(username=username, is_staff=True)
u = User.objects.get(username=user.username)
permissions =  Permission.objects.get(name='post_can_add_post')
u.user_Permission.add(permissions)
```

Comment: What is the error.Show the error traceback.

Comment: 'User' object has no attribute 'user_permission' error

Comment: can you jest tell me how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
User.objects.get_or_create(username='testuser123')
u = User.objects.get(username='testuser123')
permissions =  Permission.objects.get(codename='post.add_post')
u.user_permissions.add(permissions)
u = User.objects.get(username=<username>)
u.has_perm(permissions)      #return True
```